# Copying Alchemist Formulae Rulings?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist

I understand that Alchemist can copy spells as a Wizard could. This explicitly means that an Alchemist can copy formula out of a Wizard's spell book as long as the spell appears on the Alchemist's formula lists, and it strongly implies the an alchemist can copy formula from an arcane scroll as well. However, I can see that are some grey areas in regards to the process of copying formulas as well. With that being said, I have the following related questions:

1. Can an Alchemist copy formulae off of a divine spell? The RAW seems to be unclear on this. On the one hand, a Wizard obviously can't put divine spells into his spell book. However, it could be argued that the Alchemist can use *any* scroll to copy formulae into his formula book as long as it's on his formula list as the Wizard has the same ability in regards to his spell list.
2. Can an Alchemist copy formulae from another Alchemist's formula book? This might seem like a no-brainer, but this was never explicitly said to be something an Alchemist can do.

My question is if there are any further rulings on how an Alchemist can copy formulae into his formula book. If there aren't any such developer rulings, how would you rule on these matter?

Comment: This seems to be a question interested in rather technical details of the rules; you might consider using the [tag:rules-as-written] tag.

Answer (score 5):

### Can an Alchemist copy formulae off of a divine scroll?

**Yes, an Alchemist can copy a formula from a divine scroll if it appears on their formula list.** An Alchemist can copy spells into a formula book just like a Wizard copies spells into their spellbook. Therefore, if a Wizard can copy a divine scroll, an Alchemist would be able to as well. Because divine writing can be deciphered like arcane writing, and the rules for copying spells from scrolls does not discriminate between divine and arcane magic (it just says "a magic scroll"), a Wizard would be able to copy a divine scroll into their spellbook if it appears on their spell list. Alchemists can do the same, but they do not have to decipher the writing first, as long as the scroll's spell appears on their formula list.

### Can an Alchemist copy formulae from another Alchemist's formula book?

**There is no RAW answer**. However, one could argue that an Alchemist's ability to copy spells into formula book as a Wizard copies spells into their spellbook means they can duplicate an existing formula book like a Wizard can duplicate a spellbook. Because of that, an Alchemist would *have* to be able to copy spells between formula books. Additionally, Ultimate Magic includes a formula book in its example spellbooks, which would imply someone would be able to copy from it. Using this evidence, **an Alchemist would be able to copy formulae from another Alchemist's formula book**.

Comment: I would recommend accepting this answer as it has been 4 years since this question was originally posted and answered.